# The Center of a Matrix Ring

Tags: ring-theory

Prove that the center of the ring $M_n(R)$ is the set of scalar matrices. 
I know what a center look like but i feel like i have not enough information to even solve this problem. Anyone that can help that would be great.

Comment: Double containment is the best way to do it. Let $Z$ be the center and $D$ be the set of scalar matrices. Certainly scalar matrices are contained in the center, as $A(\lambda I) = \lambda (A I) = \lambda A = (\lambda I)A$. The other direction is a little harder. Try direct computation of a non-scalar matrix.

Comment: Please search for your question before posting your question.